# garchSim function in fGarch R package

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to simulate from a GARCH process. I do not understand the output that the garchSim function gives. Here is the code I am running:

```
library(fGarch)
set.seed(1)
model_a<-garchSpec(model=list(alpha=c(0.9,0.2, beta=0.5)), cond.dist="norm", rseed=0.9)
garch_sim_a<-garchSim(spec=model_a, n=500,n.start=0, extended=T)
```

The output is a timeseries object with a 3x3 matrix. From what I can gather the 1st column is the realisations, the second the volatility process and the third is the 'esp'. This code gives NaN values for all but the third column and I dont know why! I also don't understand what these position numbers are and why they are so large!

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The garch(p,q) is weakly stationary if and only if the sum of the parameters `alpha` and `beta` is less than 1.

Therefore, to avoid the NAs, try instead of `alpha=c(0.9,0.2),beta=0.5)` something like  `alpha=c(0.25,0.24),beta=0.5)` since 0.25 + 0.24 + 0.5 < 1.